# Is there a way to run a closure without testing it?

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

I use this scheme constantly in my classes

```
typealias nullHandle = ()->Void
var runOnLoad: nullHandle?
```

So, when I create an instance of that class I do...

```
let object = MyClass()
object.runOnLoad = { ()->Void in
  // do something
}
```

Inside the class, I always have to do this before running that closure:

```
if self.runOnLoad != nil {
  self.runOnLoad()!
}
```

because I cannot guarantee that `runOnLoad` is not nil and if I try to run a nil `runOnLoad` it will crash.

I am new to swift after programming in Objective-C for a century. I am using this pattern in swift because this is what I would do in Objective-C.

Is there a better way to do this whole thing in Swift?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) works with closures as well:

```
self.runOnLoad?()
```

executes the closure if it is not `nil`, and does nothing otherwise.

Of course you can also test the closure, but that is better done with optional binding instead of forced unwrapping:

```
if let runOnLoad = self.runOnLoad {
    runOnLoad()
}
```